# Не происходит Обновление html в тэге select в мобильном ios, jquery

Tags: jquery, ios, select, mobile

Jquery 3.4.1

Select doesnt take HTML variable in mobile ios, with picker activated. All other browsers work fine.

```js
var numberselector = '<option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option>';
$('select.magicnumber').html(numberselector);
$("#selectednumber").keyup(
  function() {
    var input = $('#selectednumber').val();
    //$("#magicnumber option[value='"+input+"']").attr("selected", "selected");
    $("#magicnumber").val(input);
    $("#magicnumbercheck").html(input);
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="selectednumber" id="selectednumber" type="number" value="1" placeholder="Введите число" style=" width: 208px; ">
<select name="magicnumber" id="magicnumber" class="magicnumber" style="width:208px;">
</select>
<!--Следующий блок для проверки-->
<div id="magicnumbercheck"></div>
```

Comment: Put an online example. You can check it from desktop and iphone. See the difference.
https://sas2.ru/jquery-ios-select.html

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю. в чём тут прикол, однако изначально мой JS был в отдельном файле, внутри такой  конструкции:

```
(function ($) {
   "use strict";
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

Как только перенёс в HTML файл, в такую функцию

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

На айфоне также стало работать. Во всех остальных браузерах, как работало так и работает. Непонятно.